# Get next element with class (while ommitting others)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
var toLoad = $('.sidebar').find('.active').next('li.list-element').attr('data-id');
```

Which should detect the *next* element after my `.active` with `list-element` class. It doesn't. The problem is, I have a list like this:

```
<li class="list-element active">...</li>
<li class="list-element">...</li>
<li class="ads">...</li>
<li class="list-element">...</li>
<li class="list-element">...</li>
```

And when I get to `ads`, my script stops. What can I do?

Comment: why don't you remove class selector and just select `li`

Comment: @bipen - it would select the `ads` li which I want to ommit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.next()` will only target the next element. You need to use `.nextAll()` along with `:first` or `:eq(0)` to target the next first sibling with the required class:

```
 var toLoad = $('.sidebar').find('.active').nextAll('li.list-element:first').attr('data-id')
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your understanding of the .next() method is wrong, it does not return the element element matching the selector, it will return the next sibling element only if it matches the passed selector

One easy solution is to find all the next elements then use the first one in the set

```
var toLoad = $('.sidebar').find('.active').nextAll('li.list-element:eq(0)').attr('data-id');
```

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of
>   matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next
>   sibling only if it matches that selector.

Answer (score 0):

So, when you write

```
$('.sidebar').find('.active')
```

That will find one element, the `li` with the class `active` and `.next()` can only select from within that group.

You could, however, use just one CSS selector to find the next element from the `.active` one like so:

```
$('.sidebar .active ~ li.list-element:first').attr('data-id')
```

`~` is the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) that matches elements that are after the original element (`.active`) and share a parent (`.sidebar`).